# Require only one codeowner on GitHub to review a PR

Tags: github

We have a GitHub repo with a `CODEOWNERS` file. For the main branch we also have a protection rule to "Require review from Code Owners". However, some folders of the repo belong to multiple code owners, and if they have changed then GitHub requires ALL code owners to approve the change.

Is there a way to tell GitHub that an approval from one of the code owners is sufficient?

(Note that there is another option in the branch protection rules, which requires approvals for a change, and one can define how many such approvals are necessry. This is not what I am looking for, I am solely talking about the review of code owners.)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Gajus Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

According to the GitHub CODEOWNERS [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners), this is possible with this example syntax:

```
# In this example, any change inside the `/scripts` directory
# will require approval from @doctocat or @octocat.
/scripts/ @doctocat @octocat
```

Also, users and teams are treated equally according to the same documentation:

```
The pattern is followed by one or more GitHub usernames or team names using the standard @username or @org/team-name format.
```

Are you experiencing a different behaviour? If so maybe post (the relevant portion of) your CODEOWNERS? It may be the case that your CODEOWNERS file is complex - see [this thread](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22522) where it says:

> It’s hard to say why you’re experiencing this behavior without some more information. Is the repository in question public? Can you share a link to a specific PR that is behaving in a way that you believe is not expected?
>
> Assuming that the repository in question is private, I can guess at one reason why more than one reviewer might be required. Let’s say you have a CODEOWNERS like the following:

```
* @foo @bar @baz
```

> In this case, any PR would require one (and only one) of those three people to approve it before it could be merged. But let’s say you have a more complex CODEOWNERS file:

```
*.js @foo @bar`
docs/ @baz`
```

> And you submit a PR that includes both a JavaScript change as well as a change to some associated documentation. That PR would require one of either foo or bar to approve it for the JavaScript change and a separate approval from baz for the documentation.
>
> Maybe you could share just your CODEOWNERS file?